# Finding a real number c for polynomial (proof)

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

The question is to find a real number c for which $ x\ge c%+$ implies $$x^4-4x^3+7x-9 \ge1000$$.

I was given the hint that $x>10$, then $4x^3<0.4x^4$, so $x^4-4x^3>0.6x^4$.

Problem is, I'm not understanding this line of reasoning, particularly how x>10 goes to the next step involving the $0.4x^4$.

Comment: The connection between the 4 and 0.4 has to do with the choice of $x > 10$. It might be easier to see if you instead reasoned that for $x > 10$, you have $x^4 > 10x^3$, so $x^4-4x^3 > 6x^3$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x > 10$ then $0.4x > 4$ and so $4x^3 < (0.4x)x^3 = 0.4x^4$. Therefore $x^4 - 4x^3 > x^4 - 0.4x^4 = 0.6x^4$.

Furthermore, if $x > 10$, then $7x - 9 \geq 7(10) -9 = 61$. Therefore, if $x > 10$, $x^4 - 4x^3 + 7x - 9 > 0.6x^4 + 61$. So how big should $x$ be so that $0.6x^4 \geq 1000?$

Answer (score 0):

That step is just a fancy way of writing 10: Note that $10x^3<x^4$ when $x>10$. Now write $10$ as $4/0.4$ to get $4x^3< 0.4x^4$.

What we are really doing is this:

Note that if "$x$ is large" then the inequality should be true. We are trying to determine how large $x$ should be. Now, $x=10$ would be the choice if we only had $x^4$ instead of the given function.

For $x=10$ the inequality is not true, as the term $-4x^3$ makes out life a bit tougher. So we want to "estimate" how big this term is compared to $x^4$.

Hope this helps.